# Tweeting out a quote from Object.textContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've build a page where I pull a random quote from an API and all is working in that regard, but I can't seem to pull the textContent and append it to the tweet button.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="quote-box">
  <div id="quote-copy">
    <i class="fa fa-quote-left" id="quotation"> </i> 
    <span class="text" id="random-quote"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="quote-author">
    - <span class="author"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="quote-buttons">
    <a class="button" id="instagram" title="follow me on IG!" target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/dopeland/"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i> Instagram</a>
    <a class="button" id="tweet-this" title="Tweet This Quote!" href="https://twitter.com/share" target="_blank" data-size="large"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tweet This!</a>
    <a class="button" id="get-quote" title="Generate a new quote!" href="">New Quote</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getQuote(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1',
      success: function(data) {
        var post = data.shift();
        $('.author').text(post.title);
        $('.text').html(post.content);
      },
      cache: false
    });
  };

function changeColor(){
  var colors = ['#7A918D', '#93B1A7', '#99C2A2', '#C5EDAC', '#DBFEB8'];
  var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (colors.length - 0));

  document.body.style.background = colors[randNum];
  $('#quotation').css('color', colors[randNum]);
};



$(document).ready(function() {
  getQuote(); 
  changeColor();

  var randomQuote = $('#random-quote')["0"].textContent;

  $('#tweet-this').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + randomQuote);
  });

  $('#get-quote').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    getQuote();
    changeColor();
  });
});
```

So my issue is that whenever I click the tweet button, I am only returned with the link "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text="

You can also view my CodePen here: https://codepen.io/dopeland/pen/XgwNdB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `var randomQuote = $('#random-quote')["0"].textContent;` inside of your `click` listener

Like so:

```
$('#tweet-this').click(function(){
    var randomQuote = $('#random-quote')["0"].textContent;
    $(this).attr('href', "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + randomQuote);
});
```

`randomQuote` is assigned once at the beginning (set to a value of `""`). Even though you are calling the `click` listener, the quote's text is never being written to `randomQuote` and always stays as `""`.

Forked and fixed codepen: https://codepen.io/eqwert/pen/owraVK